# Sharp edges during sculpting

Tags: edges

[image: picture]
How can i preserve sharp edges during sculpting without getting this? ( I used creases and edge split modifier)

Comment: You don't want to move them at all or you may move them (sculpting) but you want to keep the sharp aspect ?

Comment: edge split is the problem, it literally splits the edges as in duplicates all the vertices and edges; which when using different sculpt tools will pull the vertices apart.

Comment: @David But without the edge split creases look messy with smooth shader enabled, what should i do?

Comment: You can hide these vertices in edit mode and come back sculpting, they'll stay in place

Answer (score 1):

Well one way to do this is by using only creases and disabling the edge split modifier (This will work if you use the multiresolution modifier).